# What effect have the number of records of a particular table (in SQL Server) on LINQ Queries response time in C# MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, query-performance

I made some googling about my subject title, but didn't find useful answer. Most question were about effect of number of table's columns on query performance, while i need to know the effect of number of table's rows on linq query response time in C# MVC project. Actually, i have a web MVC project in which i try to get alarms set using ajax call from server and show them in a web grid in client side. Each ajax call is performed every 60 seconds in a loop created with setTimeOut method. Number of rows are gradually increasing within the alarm table (in SQL Server Database) and after a week, it reaches to thousands of rows. At first when lunching the project, I can see in DevTools of browser(Chrome), the time each ajax call takes is about 1 second or so. But this time gradually increases every day and after a week each success ajax call takes more than 2 minutes. This causes about 5 ajax call always be in pending queue. I am sure there is no memory leak both in client(JQuery) and server(C#) sides code, So the only culprit I suspect is SELECT Query response time performed on alarm table. I appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Check the query that is executed in the database. There are two options:

1. Your Linq query fetches **all** the data from the database and process them locally. In this case the number of rows in the table is quite important. You need to fix your Linq query and make sure it fetches only the relevant rows from the database. Then you can hit option 2.
2. Your Linq query fetches only the relevant rows from the database, but there are no relevant indexes in your table and each query scans **all** the data in the table.

However with only few thousands rows in your table, I have doubts it will take 2 minutes to scan the table, so option 1 is more likely to be the reason for this slowdown.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually i don't perform any local extra processing after fetching in LINQ SELECT Query and return the data to client side using JSON format right away. My main concern was the impact of number of table records on LINQ Query performance. By your description, i guess the impact is trivial. Right?

Comment: No, I said nothing about what you do after your Linq query. What I said is that your Linq query may fetch all the data from your table and process it locally. It depends how it's written and what you do. That's why I recommended to check what is the actual T-SQL query executed against the database. Post it here for review. Depending on that, the number of records may (if they are filtered locally) or may not (if they are filtered in the db) affect your Linq query performance.

Comment: I am on a common project and the server is in dll format. At the moment my colleague is not here to get the server class library code from her. Anyway thank you Andrey and i may comeback to this post in future days.